# Laravel: Insert multiple records with auto fill created_at & updated_at

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, orm

I am trying to save multiple records in DB and have an array which looks like:-

```
$insert_data = array(
array(record 1),
array(record 2),
array(record 3)
)
```

Now, I tried two options:-

1. `Model::create($insert_data)` But it doesn't create any entry in DB.
2. `Model::insert($insert_data)` It's creating entry in DB with null datestamps.

I wanna insert multiple records with valid timestamps.

TIA

Comment: Can we see the actual code and errors?

Comment: No, Error is there. It's just saving whole data without timestamps.

Comment: @Sahil, use `createMany` instead of `create`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`create()` is a function from Eloquent,
`insert()` - Query Builder.

You probably do not use Eloquent when inserting data, in this case you should add timestamps manually.

If you do not want to do this, but you still need filled timestamps, use this trick:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

Or, you can add `timestamp` like this :

```
$now = Carbon::now('utc')->toDateTimeString();
$data = array(
    array(
        'name'=>'Coder 1', 
         'rep'=>'4096',
        'created_at'=> $now,
        'updated_at'=> $now
       ),
    array(
         'name'=>'Coder 2', 
         'rep'=>'2048',
         'created_at'=> $now,
         'updated_at'=> $now
       ),
    //...
);

Coder::insert($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `upsert` method since Laravel 8.

```php
Model::upsert(
    array(
        array(record 1),
        array(record 2),
        array(record 3)
    ),
    'id'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Forloop your array $insert_data.

```
foreach($insert_data as $in_data){
    Model::create($in_data);
}
```

It should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Shohan, But as I mentioned i want to add multiple records with time stamp not one by one.  I want to avoid loops in my code as much as I can do. Once again thanks for your efforts and time.